# DirectX Texture Handle output from Visual studio WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, directx-11

Firstly I am a novice as far as DirectX (if that is even correct) and the GPU handling of the resources.

I believe this inexperience is hindering me in even searching for the correct terms to find an answer, so I apologize if this is frustrating.

Ideally what I am trying to do, is using WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation,visual studio 2013) I have a viewport class inside a window form. *I want to be-able to find the directX native hardware 'handle id' of that texture (from the GPU, if that is correct) and pass it over to another application called "Substance Designer" which can retrieve this data and project it to a physical screen.*

Edit: Further research has linked me to DirectX Sharing Resource if this helps at all.

Let me know if I can clear any parts of this up.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.  Are you sure there even is a DirectX handle for a viewport?  WPF is a high-level API that is designed to abstract away such details.  However, you can render the window to a Bitmap on the CPU, then pass that along to your app.  It would be slower but there are code examples out there on how to do it.

Comment: I am not sure at all, you raise a fair point I will need to investigate further to see if that is the case.

Comment: I've created controls where I've hosted regular forms controls/windows inside WPF applications before. I'm an experienced DX developer, but haven't tried to toy with it. But.. It should be possible to create a D3D rendering surface and show it in a w32 window, but you will most likely have to go all the way down to w32 c++ code.. Unfortunately I do not have the time right now to create an example for you. When you are doing this you will loose ZIndex, if I recall correctly, and other issues as well. WPF is built upon D3D. The ZIndex issue you may solve by forcing your D3D window to be on top.

Comment: Hi Stian, that is fantastic news and information. Thank you very much. If you ever find the time I would greatly appreciate an example.